# how to check "scheduled time(s) through AppCMD

Tags: iis, appcmd

iis> application pool> (recycling wizard)> i succeeded to edit "specific time(s) by appcmd.
i cant find help how to check "Scheduled time(s) through appcmd.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could get application pool recycle scheduled time by using below command

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
(Get-ItemProperty ('IIS:\AppPools\sample1') -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection) | select value
```

[image]

Note: Do not forget to run PowerShell as administrator.